# Node.js module won't reinstall using puppet / vagrant

Tags: puppet, node.js, vagrant

Previously I had a similar configuration to this working but as soon as I added hiera to my puppet build I started having problems. The error I currently have after running `vagrant provision` is as follows:

```
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Checking for host entries
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.33.10 local.mysite
==> default: Configuring cache buckets...
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with app.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Error: Could not find class nodejs for local.mysite on node local.mysite
==> default: Error: Could not find class nodejs for local.mysite on node local.mysite
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

My vagrant config is:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
require "yaml"

# Load yaml configuration
config_file = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/config/vm_config.yml"
default_config_file = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/config/.vm_config_default.yml"

vm_external_config = YAML.load_file(config_file)

# Configure Vagrant
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: vm_external_config["ip"]
  config.vm.hostname = vm_external_config["hostname"]
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: vm_external_config["port"], host: 2368

  config.vm.synced_folder vm_external_config["ghost_path"], "/var/www/mysite.com", :nfs => true

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", vm_external_config["memory"]]
  end

  config.cache.scope = :box

  config.librarian_puppet.placeholder_filename = ".gitkeep"

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera/hiera.yaml"
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "app.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.facter = {
        "environment" => ENV['ENV'] ? ENV['ENV'] : 'local'
    }
  end
end
```

My source tree looks like so (much of it isn't relevant aside from the folders structure for the custom blog module and hiera config):

```
├── Vagrantfile
├── config
│   └── vm_config.yml
└── puppet
    ├── Puppetfile
    ├── hiera
    │   ├── common.yaml
    │   ├── hiera.yaml
    │   ├── local
    │   │   └── site.yaml
    │   └── production
    │       └── site.yaml
    ├── manifests
    │   └── app.pp
    └── modules
        ├── blog
        │   └── manifests
        │       └── app.pp
        ├── ghost
        │   └── manifests
        │       └── app.pp
        ├── init.d
        │   └── files
        │       ├── WebhookServer
        │       └── ghost
        ├── mailgunner
        ├── nginx
        │   ├── files
        │   │   ├── local
        │   │   │   ├── mysite.com
        │   │   │   └── mail.mysite.com
        │   │   └── production
        │   │       ├── mysite.com
        │   │       └── mail.mysite.com
        │   └── manifests
        │       └── server.pp
        ├── tools
        │   ├── files
        │   │   ├── local
        │   │   │   ├── backup.sh
        │   │   │   ├── ghostsitemap.sh
        │   │   │   └── init-mysite.sh
        │   │   └── production
        │   │       ├── backup.sh
        │   │       ├── ghostsitemap.sh
        │   │       └── init-mysite.sh
        │   └── manifests
        │       └── install.pp
        └── webhooks
            ├── files
            │   ├── local
            │   │   └── init-webhook.sh
            │   ├── production
            │   │   └── init-webhook.sh
            │   ├── webhook.sh
            │   └── webhooks.rb
            └── manifests
                └── install.pp
```

hiera.yaml:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml

:yaml:
  :datadir: /vagrant/hieradata

:hierarchy:
  - "%{::environment}/site
  - common
```

common.yaml

```
--
classes:
  - site
```

local/site.yaml

```
--
:site:
  environment: local
  name: local.mysite
  mailserver: local.mail.mysite
```

blog/manifests/app.pp

```
class blog::app {

  class { 'nodejs':
    version => 'v0.10.25',
  } ->
  package { 'pm2':
    ensure => present,
    provider => 'npm',
    require => Class['nodejs'],
  }
}
```

Puppetfile

```
forge 'https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com'

mod 'willdurand/nodejs', '1.9.4'
```

Basically, my problem is that my puppet install is not reinstalling nodejs (I'd removed it previously using an `rm -rf puppet/modules/nodejs`)

Does anyone have any ideas how or why puppet is now refusing to install the nodejs puppet module in the puppet/modules directory?

FYI - I've installed the willdurand/nodejs module using `puppet module install willdurand/nodejs`

Any help is much appreciated - I've been banging my head against a brick wall on this for a few days now!

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to move this to StackOverflow instead as I believe it's more appropriate there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832917/node-js-module-wont-reinstall-using-puppet-vagrant

Feel free to close this question.